# Making GET request for generating sudoku

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, arraylist, rest-client

I have made a class which generates a brand new sudoku puzzle on my GenService class which takes in input int and String. Return type List> . I am trying to make GET request to link it to my front end. Can't figure out the correct method. Quite new to this stuff

Using the google ARC to test this out

```
@GetMapping(value = "/NineHard")
public List<ArrayList<Integer>> newHardNine(@RequestBody int dimension, @RequestBody String difficulty){
    gen = new GenService(NINE, "HARD");
    return gen.getPuzzle();
}
```

Receiving these errors

```
 {
    "timestamp": 1568938660534,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/solveSudoku/NineHard"
 }
```

Any help please

Comment: The error says url not exists in your application

Answer (score 0):

Path you are hitting is “/solveSudoku/NineHard”. But @Getmapping has “/NineHard” so this resource is not found and throwing 404 error. So change the @GetMapping path to “/solveSudoku/NineHard”.